# Initializing a 2d array in C

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
int main() { 
    int x, y; 
    int *xptr, *yptr; 
    int array[10][10]; 
    int j; 
    int k; 
    int z = 0; 

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
        for(k = 0; k < 10; k++) { 
            array[j][k] = j * 10 + k; 
        } 
    } 

    xptr = &array[0][0]; 

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
        for(k = 0; k < 10; k++) { 
            printf("array[%d][%d] = %d \n", j, k, *(xptr + j), (xptr + k)); 
        } 
    } 

    system("PAUSE"); 
}
```

I am trying to initialize a 2d array so that at [0][0] it equals 0 and at [9][9] it equals 99.  With the way that it is now, [0][0-9] all equal 0 and then [1][0-9] all equal 1.  How would I properly load this array in the fashion that I mentioned?

Comment: Where is `z` coming from?  I see no declaration.

Comment: Oh and z is initialized to 0.

Comment: This really should work...how is `array` declared? Post a complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The outside can't be too much different from [this one](http://liveworkspace.org/code/77ce8bd865118dfad99119d23cd647e0), can it?

Comment: Have you perhaps accidentally fixed your mistake when typing the code here and in your problematic code the `z++` is in the outer loop?

Comment: I tried adding the z++ to my outer loop and that didn't fix the problem either.  Could it possibly be in the way that it is being printed?

Comment: Take note that you pass 4 additional arguments to `printf` when it expects 3.

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem.  The issue wasn't with declaring my array.  It was with printing it.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      for(k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            array[j][k] = j*10 + k;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've actually declared everything, but didn't include it in the example. You simply want

`array[j][k] = j*10 + k;`